# matrix from txt fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have a txt file like this:

```
 24.2 30.6 23.9 23.7 26.5 24.7
 24.4 30.4 24.1 23.8 26.3 24.7
 24.2 30.5 24.4 23.6 26.2 25.1
 24.5 30.4 23.9 23.8 26.1 24.8
 24.0 30.4 24.3 23.5 26.3 25.0
```

I can not read into a matrix(5,6), Fortran runtime error: End of file

the code is:

```
open(11,file='aux.txt',status='old',decimal='comma')

  open(13,file='temperatura.txt',status='replace')
  open(14,file='temperaturamod.txt',status='old')  

do i=1,fil

      READ (11,*)t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6       
      WRITE (13,'(6F5.1)')t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6
  end do

  DO i = 1,5
    DO j = 1,6
     READ (13,*) matriz (i,j) 
    END DO
  END DO
```

Comment: In the piece you have posted, you have not initialized `fil`. Isn't `fil = 5`?

Comment: I don't think the inclusion of `decimal='comma'` in the statement to open that data file is desirable.  It may even be harmful.

Comment: Actually, now that I've had a chance to test it, the inclusion of `decimal='comma'` doesn't seem to matter -- at least not for a fairly recent version of gfortran working on this example input file.  I don't know if this is standard-conforming behaviour or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read data to `matriz` line by line:

```
  DO i = 1,5
     READ (13,*) matriz (i,:) 
  END DO
```

Or

```
  DO i = 1,5
     READ (13,'(6F5.1)') matriz (i,:) 
  END DO
```

And you have to reopen file unit 13 for reading or put cursor to the start of the file: `rewind(13)`.